C program called in a bash loop incrementally reading from a single file never exiting
int main() {
    char buf[2];
    read((0, buf, 2);
    lseek(0, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    write(1, buf, 2);
}

The rwl program, whose source code is shown on the top, is run with the following command on a 2-line fileA text file with "01234" data on each line. Determine the data that this command will display and the changes that must be made to the rwl source code in order for the command to be terminated.
$> while rwl; do :; done < fileA
This is an old exam question. Can someone help me solve it?
I tried to put a while(read(0, buf, 2) > 0) and put other 2 inside of loop but it didnt work.

What's the specific technical question you need answered to be able to sove the question yourself? There are several different moving parts here, which makes the overall "solve this exam question" request as currently written something that isn't narrow and specific as our scoping rules require.

(arguably you could change the C program to run only exit(1); and do nothing else, and that would satisfy the requirement of making the loop exit).

When the code runs it prints 01340134 and then never finishes. It just tries to keep reading. I'm trying to make program to terminate after reading the file.

Great -- make sure it calls exit(1) when the read fails. As with pretty much all other kinds of error handling in C, that means you need to pay attention to return values and to errno.

btw, I'd argue that this code is deliberately obfuscatory insofar as it uses a constant integer for the whence argument to lseek rather than one of the more readable constant names. You might want to go look up what 1 means in the whence value and replace it accordingly for easier understanding.

oh it means SEEK_CUR i just wrote 1

What makes you think that the loop could ever terminate?

This is a C problem more than a bash problem: Your program isn't checking for errors, so it never detects that it was unable to read additional content from the file successfully, and correspondingly never tells bash that it failed -- so the loop never exits.
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buf[2];
    int retval;

    retval = read(0, buf, 2);
    if (retval != 2) { exit(1); }

    retval = lseek(0, 1, SEEK_CUR);
    if (retval < 0) { exit(1); }

    retval = write(1, buf, 2);
    if (retval != 2) { exit(1); }
}


it never detects that it was unable to read and write successfully  Oh, the original code will keep writing successfully...

@AndrewHenle, sure, writing NULs (which the terminal ignores). It's a success from the syscall's perspective, though, granted.

If stdout is redirected to a file, they won't be ignored...

Omg it worked thank you so much

I told you it would work in the comments almost an hour ago. Not sure why you had to wait for the answer.
